# MRTK V2.2 - Spatial Mapping starts automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

Updated to Mrtk 2.2 and now realizing that I cant disable spatial mapping at the start. I can disable it on runtime, but the checkbox under `Spatial Awareness System Settings > Spatial Mesh Observer Settings > Startup Behavior` is not working.

### To reproduce

Set under `Spatial Awareness System Settings > Spatial Mesh Observer Settings` the value of Startup Behavior to `manual start`.

### Screenshot

[image]

### My Specs

- Unity Version 2019,3
- MRTK Version v2.2

### What else I tried

Recreated my profiles; ported via guide;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me; I outcommented the content of Enable in line 147 under `Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Providers\WindowsMixedReality\WindowsMixedRealitySpatialMeshObserver.cs`

```
 public override void Enable()
 {
     //if (!IsRunning)
     //{
     //    Resume();
     //}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this! This has been [fixed in the development branch](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/6919) and will ship with [MRTK 2.3](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Contributing/Roadmap.html#upcoming-releases).